# getFragmentById returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, null

I've never used Fragments before but now I have a PlayerStatus fragment, that I want to use in two different activities. It shows player status:

```
public class PlayerStatus extends Fragment {
Player player;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_status, container, false);
    return view;
}

public void setPlayer(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}
```

}

Fragment's layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="0dp" >

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    layout="@layout/money" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    layout="@layout/wins" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    layout="@layout/level" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get it in the activity this way:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    fPlayerStatus = (PlayerStatus)       getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fPlayerStatus);
```

fPlayerStatus always returns null. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about how to start fragments ,attach/detach from activity , what does commit() do and there are few more basic functions which you should know when using fragments

[http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

[Fragment Basics Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

go through these web sites and you'll definately get through with fragments easily .

To make your fragments work here you have to do the following :
1.Add your fragment to your activity
  write the following

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.YOUR_FRAGMENT_ID_AS_DEFINED_IN_XML , object of your fragment class)

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*___END----------------------------------

There are many other useful methods in the APIs from FragmentTransaction , read them through the link above and you'll be abel to use them easily

Lemme know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you! It helped - now I have IllegalArgumentException, not NPE :)   I've read those articles several times and I wanted to add fragment statically through xml layout => (as described in developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding ) "When the system creates this activity layout, it instantiates each fragment specified in the layout and calls the onCreateView() method for each one, to retrieve each fragment's layout. The system inserts the View returned by the fragment directly in place of the <fragment> element."

Comment: So I thought that I do not have to use fragmentTransactions (and framelayout). But now - using fragmentTransactions - I'm supposed to use frameLayout, yes?

Comment: you mean the Main layout in your xml file where the fragments defined . nop you can use any layout irrespectively

Comment: 12-13 16:12:46.919: E/AndroidRuntime(12501): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {app.lws/app.lws.ui.game.GameActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f040065 (app.lws:id/fPlayerStatus) for fragment PlayerStatusFragment{42ed1c48 #0 id=0x7f040065 fPlayerStatus}

I've changed a bit your piece of code, fragment has unique id and unique tag. I've set contentview in onCreate and in onResume, but... help me pls, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your fragment has not been added to the `FragmentManager` in your Activity.
First do a `FragmentTransaction` with `beginTransaction().add(...)` on the `getFragmentManager()`.
And don't forget to `commit()` it.

Comment: But I thought (because of this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding ) that as I added fragment in xml it should be instantiated by system?

Answer (score 0):

I don't Think you can use one Fragment for two Activities.
As i think your approach should be

Step 1

Create two fragment Layouts in your Activity_main

Step 2

then use fragment manager in your activity like below

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();  

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame,fragment) 

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: nop thats the best part of Fragments ,they are used because they are reusable , you can very well use a fragment in two different activities without any problem because you make two different objects and pass those two objects to the two different activity .